# Is it possible to use direct air capture technology for CO2 on a non-commercial level?

Tags: chemical-engineering, chemistry

CO2 is used as fertilizer in aquariums where it's brought into the water with diffusors from compressed form in cylinders. [Direct Air Capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_removal#Direct_air_capture) machines for CO2 have been presented for experimental geo-engineering purposes.

I was wondering whether it's possible to use the technology on a much smaller scale which allows one to supply the fertilizer as a constant CO2 stream (a few g per hours) or somehow compress the CO2 into a cylinder to produce it at home. This should avoid the the need for at least transport and energy for compression and allows to near endless supply for free.

Could I emit CO2 certificates? Just kidding...

Comment: plant a tree...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible and this is currently being done at the OpenAir Collective. There are two direct air carbon capture (DACC) machines under active development, Violet and Cyan. Both are small-scale, open-sourced, non-commercial systems that could be used to take CO2 out of the air and to supply it as fertilizer to plants. These units do not offer CO2 compression into a cylinder however.

Violet is OpenAir's version of a prototype system by Prof. Tao Wang; his prototype captures about 1 kg CO2 per day and releases it into a greenhouse to improve plant growth. Here is a photo of his system. It operates in cycles so some storage will be required to supply CO2 as a constant stream.

[image: Photograph of the moisture-swing prototype]

Violet is still being developed at present but the prototype system above is currently in service.

Cyan is an even smaller system buildable for under $100 that presently captures a few grams per day and locks the CO2 into calcium carbonate. The CO2 can be released through combination with vinegar or other acids. Cyan is a very portable unit that can be used at home.

[image: Photograph of the outside of the Cyan unit]

Comment: Please add any details to this post instead of linking to them. Without the specific details that answer the question, this post is somewhere between a "link-only" answer and "spam or self promotion".

Comment: Thank you @hazzey, I'd appreciate guidance on additional details that would help answer this question. The question was whether it was possible and I demonstrated that it was possible and attempted to provide evidence that this technology is in use. I have removed the links, hopefully that will help.